# Visual studio 2015 can't load kmdf project

Tags: visual-studio-2015, wdk

I get this error while loading kmdf project
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\build\WindowsDriver.Default.props(17,20): A numeric comparison was attempted on "$(WindowsTargetPlatformVersion)" that evaluates to "" instead of a number, in condition "'$(OverrideCfgV1)' == '' and '$(WindowsTargetPlatformVersion)' <= '10.0.14250.0'".

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try going to Project Properties -> General -> Windows SDK Version -> set to the correct SDK version you have installed.

Make sure you have Windows 10 SDK installed, otherwise you cannot do the above step. If you don't have it installed, install it and then try loading the project without doing the above.

You can find Windows 10 SDK here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk

I hope this helped.